# Distribution of Levenshtein distances for partially sorted lists

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a partially sorted list of distinct items and want to know the probability of this occurring by happenstance rather than intent.

The Levenshtein distance is a good metric for the problem domain.

What is needed is the probability distribution of Levenshtein distances for partially sorted lists compared to a fully sorted list.

A search has turned up one [related paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/q-bio/0601006), but this applies to the case of the alphabet size being much shorter than the list size.  For my problem the alphabet size is the same as the list length.

More exactly: Two lists, $L_1$ and $L_2$ where the elements in $L_1$ are sorted and $L_2$ contains the same elements as $L_1$ in some order. Compute the Levenshtein distance between $L_1$ and $L_2$ where $L_2$ takes on all possible permutations of the elements in $L_1$. Given this set of distances I can plot Levenshtein distance against the number of permutations having a given distance, this is the distribution I am after.

My lists are short'ish, around 20 or so items, so with some work all distances might be enumerated (there are some obvious optimizations to speed up the $n^2$ algorithm when permuting through the set of partially sorted lists).  The work could be reduced further by only considering versions of $L_2$ having elements that are, say, 90% sorted relative to $L_1$.

Comment: By "partially sorted lists" do you mean unsorted lists, i.e. are you interested in the distribution over all permutations of the lists, or does "partially sorted" indicate some skewing towards partial sortedness? If so, you'd need to quantify that.

Comment: I expect the lists I am measuring to have many elements sorted, say 90% in sort order.  I'm happy to ignore any lists that don't have a reasonable degree of sortedness (sorry for delay in replying).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "happy to ignore". You say you need the probability distribution -- which one? There's no well-defined question here unless you specify either that you want the distribution of the distances among all permutations or how you're choosing the "partially sorted" lists.

Comment: Two lists, $L_1$ and $L_2$ where the elements in $L_1$ are sorted and $L_2$ contains the same elements as $L_1$ in some order.  Compute the Levenshtein distance between $L_1$ and $L_2$ where $L_2$ takes on all possible permutations of the elements in $L_1$.  Given this set of distances I can plot Levenshtein distance against the number of permutations having a given distance, this is the distribution I am after.

Comment: That's a well-defined problem. I don't see how it relates to "partially sorted" lists. In fact, not even the fact that $L_1$ is sorted is relevant; the entire comparison operation between the items doesn't enter into the question at all and is merely a distraction. The problem would be more economically stated as finding the distribution of Levenshtein distances between a string of distinct letters and all its permutations.

Comment: Unless there is an analytic solution the problem is computationally intensive.  Limiting the search space to the set of lists that are close to $L_1$, in the sense of being a partially sorted version of it significantly reduces the computational effort.  You are right that the original question is not clear, I will update t.

Answer (score 0):

The probability distribution of Levenshtein in the general case appears to be an open problem. If you are willing to use an approximation, you can use Monte Carlo simulation to generate the distribution under random sorting. Specifically, your simulation would begin with a sorted list; then randomly substitute, insert, or delete items; then compute the Levenshtein distance between the original and randomized list; and repeat over thousands of iterations. The proportion of iterations where Levenshtein $= d$ is the probability of obtaining that distance by chance.

The difficulty in this approach is in defining simulation parameters: number of substitutions, insertions, and deletions each; positions in the list where they occur; letters of the alphabet inserted or substituted. If we consider only the first parameter, and if we assume no more than $j$ operations ($x$ substitutions + $y$ insertions + $z$ deletions $= j$ operations) are performed on the original list, then the total number of ways the list can be randomly sorted using these three operations is $3^{j}$ + $3^{j - 1}$ + $3^{j - 2}$ + ... + $3^1$ + $3^0$). That quickly becomes a very large number of cells when *j* is not very small (e.g., 88,573 cells for $j = 10$), and a comprehensive simulation would have, say, $10,000$ reps or so per cell. Multiply that by the number of (nested) cells of the other two simulation parameters and it's apparent why the problem has not been solved mathematically.

Granted, there are simplifying assumptions that may be appropriate for your particular scenario, and you could sample cells probabilistically rather than simulating all conditions. But every step away from the complete simulation results in a rougher approximation of the answer you want.

Alternatively, you could use a version of the Hamming distance metric, which is much simpler because it allows substitutions only. Hamming is only truly appropriate under two assumptions: 1. each list is a permutation of exactly *n* distinct items (i.e., the number of letters in the alphabet equals *n* and every letter in the alphabet appears exactly once in each list), and 2. the mechanism that produces the partially-sorted list from the sorted list consists entirely of substitutions. Obviously, the second assumption is violated if, as in the Levenshtein distance, the sorting mechanism also involves insertions and deletions. However, even then, you may find that insertions and deletions are sufficiently rare that the impact of the violation is negligible, or that the degree of error in your answer is worth not using the more complex edit distance.

The "version" of Hamming referred to above is an obscure correlation statistic called the matching statistic or $m$. $m$ is equal to the number of matches between permuted lists, or $n$ minus the Hamming distance. When the two assumptions above hold, $m$ is distributed asymptotically $Poisson$ with parameter $1$ if the new list is just a random permutation of the original. This means the probability of getting a partially-sorted list with $k$ entries in their original positions (or $n - k$ in new positions) by chance is equal to the probability of drawing the value $k$ at random from a $Poisson(1)$ distribution. The approximation to $Poisson(1)$ improves rapidly with increasing $n$, and it's quite close with as few as four items.

Citations for *m*:

Vernon, P. E. (1936). The matching method applied to investigations of personality. *Psychological Bulletin*, 33(3), 149.

Vernon, P. E. (1936). The evaluation of the matching method. *Journal of Educational Psychology*, 27(1), 1.